# Power BI - Stop Rounding in Visual

Tags: powerbi, rounding

I would like my Power BI visual to show the same data values in the Quantity column as are shown in the data table (see images below).  The column is set to a Decimal Number data type in the General format using the Auto decimal places.  I do not want to change the column to a fixed decimal place as the amount of decimal places varies greatly inside this column.

How do I get my Quantity column to display the same values in my visuals as it does in my data tables?

```
Visual - Showing Automatic Rounding[1]
Data Table - Showing No Rounding[2]
Format - Column Formatting[3]
Format - Visual Field Formatting[4]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fL8U.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wrL2.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG84y.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNUZi.png
```

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: You'd be better off turning off Auto rounding. If the number of decimals varies greatly then you should extend the precision to the highest number of decimal places you expect to need.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  How do I turn off Auto rounding in Power BI Desktop?

Comment: Is there no option for having the Power BI visual show the same data values as shown in the data table (image 2)?  I have to extend all of the values out to the largest decimal place?

Comment: There is an option for that. I don't remember what it is, but look up resources to have it stop rounding entirely

Comment: Thanks.  How do I look up resources to have it stop rounding entirely?

Comment: I meant like google articles on stopping rounding. That's a slightly different question than this one

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine for Table visuals. It's harder to get a label on charts other than the tooltip.

Add a DAX Column to your table:

```
# of decimals = IF([Num]=INT([Num]),0,LEN([Num])-FIND(".",[Num],1))
```

This will return the number of decimal places of each number.

Then use this DAX measure to format the numbers in your visual:

```
Sum with significant digits = FORMAT(SUM('Table'[Num]),
"#,0." & REPT(0,MAX( MAX('Table'[# of decimals]) ,1)))
```

The `MAX('Table'[# of decimals])` will get the highest precision and the `Max(...,1)` will give you at least one decimal place for integers. You could code around that further if you prefer.

Comment: TheRizza, thanks for sharing.  However, the "Sum with significant digits" measure ends up just being a text data type that can't be changed to number data type.  That being the case I could easily change the [Num] column to a text data type without the additional DAX columns and achieve the same result.  How do I keep the column a number data type and have the table visualization show the same decimal places provided by the source data?

Comment: If you are using the table visualization, why not use the text data type? You could also get the text label on a chart using Charticulator.  Here's a walkthrough https://blog.enterprisedna.co/create-a-bar-chart-visualization-with-charticulator/